# Connect to multiple elasticsearch hosts with different username and password

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

As per spring data elasticsearch [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients.configuration), we can have multiple comma separated hosts, but it takes a single username and password.
Is it possible to configure different username and password per host?

For example, localhost:9200 -> username=user1 & password=password1, localhost:9300 ->username=username2 & password=password2

I'm using Spring Boot 2.5.2  with elasticsearch starter (which internally uses elasticsearch 4.2.x)

Answer (score 0):

Multiple hosts in the configuration are multiple nodes in the same cluster, and there you'd only have username/password.

You *can* principally create multiple `ElasticsearchRestTemplate` instances programmatically providing different `ResHighLevelClients`which you have to create by yourself as well, but this will not work with repositories, as there  you will need a single bean of type `ElasticsearchOperations`. And it is not possible just by providing some configuration, but you'd need to setup up these by yourself.

Comment: this is wrong, you can always use a ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory to programmatically instantiate a repository using an instance of ElasticsearchOperations